# If a problem is Cook-reducible to a problem in NEXP, is it in NEXP too?

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, nondeterminism

I get why that would be true for EXP but cannot extend the argument to NEXP.

Comment: All problems in coNEXP are Cook-reducible to problems in NEXP.

Comment: What about if each occurrence of "NEXP" is replaced by "NEXP or coNEXP" in my question?

Comment: Probably not. In computability theory, the Turing-closure of the halting problem is $\Delta_2$, which is above $\Sigma_1$ and $\Pi_1$. This is a consequence of [Post's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%27s_theorem).

Comment: Sorry, could you explain how that implies that there can exist a problem that is Cook-reducible to a problem in NEXP or coNEXP without being in NEXP or coNEXP?

Comment: It doesn't. I'm just giving a similar example from a related area.